# Why multiple versions of initrd.img? Can I remove them somehow?

Tags: boot, apt, kernel

I was doing `apt upgrade` on my server, that usually goes quick and doesn't break anything.
Not this time.
Here's what I got on console:

```
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.20) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-140-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-139-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-122-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-45-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-43-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-41-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-39-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
```

This went very, very slow and choked my server for like 5 minutes. Very, very bad.
Is all that necessary? It looks like those files are generated for many different versions.
Why? Do I need multiple versions? I don't want them. I want one. The latest.
And I definitely don't want the server to hang for 5 minutes on update.

So - what can I do to make things faster and get one "generating..." instead of 9 or more?

UPDATE:
I'm after `apt autoremove` and `purge-old-kernels`, anyway...

> apt-mark showmanual | grep linux

```
console-setup-linux
libselinux1
linux-base
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-37
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-37-generic
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-38
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-38-generic
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-39
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-39-generic
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-41
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-41-generic
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-43
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-43-generic
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-45
linux-cloud-tools-4.13.0-45-generic
linux-cloud-tools-virtual
linux-generic
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-39-generic
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-41-generic
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic
linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic
linux-virtual
util-linux
walinuxagent
```

Comment: Is sudo apt autoremove   - - purge working?

Comment: @nobody IDK. It shows "following packages will be removed" and all are listed. Then it shows "Removing" only for 2 of them. So I'm not sure if all were removed, or only some of them.

Comment: I am on mobile apt-mark showmanual | grep Iinux please show us.

Comment: Added to post. Looks like despite all there's still some old stuff there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is special script named `purge-old-kernels`.

To use it you need to install [single package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=purge-old-kernels) and run the script:

```
sudo apt-get install byobu
sudo purge-old-kernels
```